# how to quickly dry out home made marshmallows?

Tags: candy

I just made home made marshmallows for a birthday party in 7 hrs. How do I dry them out quickly? I used Ina G. recipe, she suggests to sit overnight, but on line it says to sit 8 hrs to dry. I need to dry them sooner, can I put them in the fridge for how long? should I put them in a cold over? Help someone, please.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Have you dusted or rolled them in powdered sugar?

Comment: Can't you use a table fan ?

Answer (score 1):

If the marshmallow batter is set/firm (not runny) and already cut into pieces, simply combine equal parts cornstarch and powdered/confectioners sugar and toss or roll the pieces in the mixture. Tap or shake off excess powder and you should be fine!